# How to create a new pk if there is no pk in the table i refers to

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am working on a web project using [django drf](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).
There was a problem during the development, so I want someone who can help me.

First, let me show you my models.

**Container**

```py
class Container(models.Model):
    cont_no = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    cont_sz = models.ForeignKey('Size', models.PROTECT, db_column='cont_sz')
    cont_type = models.ForeignKey(
        'Type', models.PROTECT, db_column='cont_type')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'container'
```

**Size**

```py
class Size(models.Model):
    sz = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)
    use_yn = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'size'
```

**Type**

```py
class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    use_yn = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'type'
```

**Import**

```py
class Import(models.Model):
    wo_no = models.OneToOneField(
        'Wo', models.PROTECT, db_column='wo_no', primary_key=True)
    cont_no = models.ForeignKey(
        Container, models.PROTECT, db_column='cont_no', blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=6)
        .
        .
        .
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'import'
```

As you can see, the `cont_no` field in the **Import** table refers to the **Container** table.

The following data exists in the **Container** table:

```
   cont_no   | cont_sz | cont_type
-------------+---------+------------
 ABCD0000001 | 4000    | DRY
 ABCD0000002 | 2000    | DRY
 ABCD0000003 | 4000    | DRY
```

I want a new value with pk '*ABCD0000004*' in the **Container** table when the `cont_no` of the data present in the **Import** table is changed to '*ABCD0000004*' using the `patch` method.

The method I tried is to define the save function of the model:

```py
class Import(models.Model):
        .
        .
        .
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        all_containers = Container.objects.all()
        size = Size.objects.get(sz='40ST')
        type = Type.objects.get(type='DRY')

        for container in all_containers:
            if container.cont_no == self.cont_no.cont_no:
                print("Match found:", container)
                break
            else:
                new_container = Container(cont_no=self.cont_no, cont_sz=size, cont_type=type)
                new_container.save()
                print("Save new container:", new_container)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'import'
```

It's a similar code, but I tried one more time:

```py
class Import(models.Model):
        .
        .
        .
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        size = Size.objects.get(sz='40ST')
        type = Type.objects.get(type='DRY')

        try:
            container = Container.objects.get(cont_no=self.cont_no.cont_no)
            print(container)

        except Container.DoesNotExist:
            new_container = Container(cont_no=self.cont_no.cont_no, cont_sz=size, cont_type=type)
            new_container.save()
            print(new_container)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'import'
```

However, all of the above methods cause the following error.

```
"PATCH /test/import/IM2302130001 HTTP/1.1" 400 35117

"cont_no": [
        "Invalid pk \"ABCD0000004\" - object does not exist."
    ]
```

Comment: 400 error often means that you are calling is_valid() method on serializer and it's not valid, sjhow your views

Comment: Serializer and Viewset are very simple for testing.  

class ImportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    class Meta:  
        model = models.Import  
        fields = '__all__'  
  
class Import(imp.ImportViewSet):  
    pass

Answer (score 1):

```
class Import(models.Model):
        .
        .
        .
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        size = Size.objects.get(sz='40ST')
        type = Type.objects.get(type='DRY')

        try:
            container = Container.objects.get(cont_no=self.cont_no.cont_no)
        except Container.DoesNotExist:
            container = Container(cont_no=self.cont_no.cont_no, cont_sz=size, cont_type=type)
            container.save()

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How about calling save method of superclass?
I just add last line to call the save method.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error occurs...
Thank you for your valuable reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`get_or_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) in the following way:

```py
class Import(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        size = Size.objects.get(sz='40ST')
        type = Type.objects.get(type='DRY')

        container, created = Container.objects.get_or_create(
            cont_no=self.cont_no.cont_no,
            defaults={'cont_sz': size.sz,
                      'cont_type': type.type})

        if created:
            print("New Container has been created", container)
        else:
            print("Container already exists", container)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'import'
```

Comment: Thank you for your good reply. I thought it was a really good approach, but it makes me get the same error... Thank you for letting me know the new way. :)

Comment: @JiseoupLim Did the problem solve yet or not?